# Unity Build vs the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, editor

friends
I have a problem when it comes to my builds, whenever I create a build it is not the same as how it is on the editor. Why is that?

I included the code I think is responsible for my problem, but I do not really understand.
isPlaying is a boolean that I trigger by a button and speed is a float value I change by a slider.

```
void Update()
{       
    if(isPlaying){
        if(startTime==0f){
            startTime= Time.time;
        }
        fps = 1/Time.deltaTime;
        timeSlider.value += (1000/fps) *speed; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What differences are you seeing between build and editor?

Comment: pls add desired result and the result which you are getting when you build.

Comment: If you are building on a platform with touch input, you may have forgotten to make the button touchable. It will work with a mouse click (in the editor), but won't work in the build.